# a one-off rewrite rule

Tags: url-rewriting, htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have *one* page that I need to change the URL for.

Currently, the page resides at example.com/departments/human-resources/

(human-resources is a sub-page of /departments/ )

My client wants to maintain the legacy url for the hr department which is:

http://example.com/hr/

How can I rewrite any request for `^/hr/?$` to `^/departments/human-resources/$` but keep the URL the same?

That is, nobody will ever see /departments/human-resources/.

My current .htaccess looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I've tried adding a rewrite rule that writes /hr/ to /dept/h-r/ before the index.php line, but this gives me a 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Redirection](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/) allows you to modify post slugs and keeps a history of them, pointing all requests for the history of a page to the same destination. It's useful for all sorts of other things too, but it will definitely solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

One time rewrite rules are actually built into the post type edit/new UI.

You can either use the *Permalink* edit line below the title or open the *Screen Options* tab and set the meta box to *visible* (check the checkbox).

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, I won't be able to removed the /departments/ before the human resources part. by using this method

Comment: @jessh _"How can I rewrite any request for `^/hr/?$` to `^/departments/human-resources/$`"_ clearly states the opposite.

Comment: no... The request URI would be `http://example.com/hr/`. This should redirect to `http://example.com/departments/human-resources/`. Your solution will only let me change whatever comes after /departments/